# Recursive template Ember/Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

For some reason, I can't call my helper in my template. It throws an error saying that my helper is undefined.

I've got the following code :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="catalog">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <ul class="list-group">
            {{#each catalog.catalog_categories}}
               {{categoryHelper this}} // This works !!!
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="categories-template" data-template-name='test' type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapse{{ category.category_id }}" data-target=".child{{ category.category_id }}">
        <li class="list-group-item">
           {{ category.category_name_fr_sh }} // French name of category
        </li>      

    </a>
    {{#if category.category_children}}     
        {{#each category.category_children}} 
            {{categoryHelper this}} // This throw error saying that the helper is undefined
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}} 
</script>

//app.js
Ember.Handlebars.helper('categoryHelper', function(category) {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($('script#categories-template').html());
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(template({category: category}));
});
```

EDIT: 
Here's a jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/CycS8/

Comment: @RoyDaniels I updated my answer with a link to my jsfiddle. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ember bootstrap, it will look for all templates with the selector `script[type="text/x-handlebars"], script[type="text/x-raw-handlebars"]`, and for each template it will compile with the appropriate compiler engine:

`Ember.Handlebars.compile` for scripts with `type="text/x-handlebars` and `Handlebars.compile` for `type="text/x-raw-handlebars`.

After the compilation the script tag is removed from the dom.

Probally the `$('script#categories-template').html()` in your helper is returning nothing. Because the template isn't in the dom.

I think that the following could work:

**templates**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="catalog">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <ul class="list-group">
            {{#each catalog.catalog_categories}}
               {{categoryHelper this}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="categories-template" type="text/x-raw-handlebars">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapse{{ category.category_id }}" data-target=".child{{ category.category_id }}">
        <li class="list-group-item">
           {{ category.category_name_fr_sh }} // French name of category
        </li>    
    </a>
    {{#each category.category_children}} 
        {{categoryHelper this}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('categoryHelper', function(category) {
    var template = Ember.TEMPLATES['categories-template'];
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(template({category: category}));
});
```

**UPDATE**

Ember provide the [render](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper) view helper, I think that you can get this working using the following:

```
<script id="catalog" type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <ul class="list-group">
            {{#each catalog.catalog_categories}}
               {{render "categories-template" this}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="categories-template" type="text/x-handlebars">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapse{{ category.category_id }}" data-target=".child{{ category.category_id }}">
        <li class="list-group-item">
           {{ category.category_name_fr_sh }} // French name of category
        </li>          
    </a>
    {{#each category.category_children}} 
        {{render "categories-template" this}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I tried what you said, the template is undefined after the Ember.TEMPLATES['categories-template']. Any idea why?

Comment: You are welcome! What `Ember.keys(Ember.TEMPLATES)` show for you?

Comment: To make things easier, I made a print screen. You have on the left, my html (its .html.twig), on the right my app.js, bottom is the Chrome EmberJS Tool result.
http://i.imgur.com/1RFgmb1.png

Comment: I will give a look in this later. But I think that you will need to change your implementation to use `{{render "categories-template" category}}` instead of the helper. Since in your helper you just want to render the template right?

Comment: Hey man, I can't thank you enough. I wasn't even aware of the render helper. I'm new to ember and there is so much to learn! I did some research and ended up tweaking the code and now it works. Update your answer with that, maybe it will help someone in the future. You mind me asking you since how long you work with ember ? Is the learning curve very hard (first JS MVC framework I use)? Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help! Answering your questions: I use since the version 1.0.pre, I think that was released one year ago. About the MVC frameworks, I started using backbone, without success, after spinejs, and the last  emberjs. I really enjoy the ember approach of MVC in client side. Databinding, computed property, integrated routing, app structure, convention over configuration etc. In the moment ember have several features, this become the learning curve hard. But with pratice you will learn.

Comment: @MarcioJunior Thank you for the code snippet!

I don't think you need the `{{#if category.category_children}}` conditional in `categories-template` because handlebars won't render `#each` when the property is falsy.

Comment: You're right @MatthewBlancarte, thanks for the correction! I updated the anwer.

Answer (score 0):

Your type is wrong, it should be `type="text/x-handlebars"` in your `test` template.

Comment: Granted, now that I look at your code, I'm not positive about it working after the compile , let me see if I can setup a jsbin.

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't work. An error gets thrown : You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined. I think it's because the compile expect a string and you can't get a string out of the type text/x-handlebars.